# How difficult is it to confirm a Bitcoin Block?

Tags: hash, difficulty

If I have done the math right to come up with this hash, to confirm a true block and this is a confirmed hash. You can look it up here [Bitcoin Block #570240](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/00000000000000000027b68db9d26885fec8dd3e785013f2355271b3ed991829)

00000000000000000027b68db9d26885fec8dd3e785013f2355271b3ed991829

That should be 64 digits. If I try it on my phone calculator, is it y to the x power the right button to push? That gives a result of 26 lowercase letters + numbers 10 to equal 36. Would I push in 36 y to the 64 power? That gives a result of 4.01199191 to 99 digits long almost 100.

Is that math right for how many combinations there are?

Comment: It's in hexadecimal, so that's 10 digits and 6 letters.

Comment: Plus a valid block hash isn't a predetermined 256-bit (64-hexit) value, which would be completely infeasible; it's any value below the current target, often approximated by a number of leading zero bits or hexits. The target for that block (and all until the next recomputation) requires zeros for about 74 bits, or 18.5 hexits. A more exact cost is obtained by multiplying the difficulty shown at that link by 2^32 = 4294967296.